# How to change the type of a field in realm studio

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I've create a class in realm studio and added a field with the wrong type (string instead of int).

It seems to be impossible, to change the type nor remove the incorrect field. Removing the complete class seems to be impossible to?

Is there a way in Realm Studio, to correct these changes? Undo is also not working.

Comment: Is it a regular Realm file or is it Sync (ROS / Realm Cloud)?

Comment: Although either way I'm not sure if Realm Studio supports destructive changes yet. Considering they're generally disallowed in Sync mode, it was never actually a priority... https://forum.realm.io/t/unable-to-edit-class-properties-in-ros/884